# How to display an image in a thumbnail gallery when you need to call the image using __doPostBack?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dopostback

Backstory: I use auctiva to post on ebay. I have been working on creating my own custom template, but am getting stuck when I want to make a gallery with thumbnails (where when you click or mouse over the thumbnails you see different image). I already have the code for the gallery sorted out. However, with the way that auctiva uses tags to let you put things in place, you cant get the link of the images.

You have to click on the tags IMAGE 1, etc. to simply place place that image into your template. You never get to see the code that they use. I went into the INSPECT ELEMENT when you left click and got the code that way. 
I think the code that pertains to this section is:

```
<font size="2"><a onclick="javascript: return   insertField(getImageTag(1));" id="dl_ImageTags__ctl0_lbtn_Image" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dl_ImageTags$_ctl0$lbtn_Image','')">Image 1</a></font>
```

The code for my gallery that I use right now is

```
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">body {
        background: #222;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      h3 {
        color: #eee;
        font-family: Verdana;
      }

      .thumbnails img {
        height: 80px;
        border: 4px solid #555;
        padding: 1px;
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
      }

      .thumbnails img:hover {
        border: 4px solid #00ccff;
        cursor:pointer;
      }

      .preview img {
        border: 4px solid #444;
        padding: 1px;
        width: 400px;
      }
</style>
<div align="center" class="gallery">


<div class="thumbnails">
```

```
onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" src="" /> 
<img alt="Image Not Loaded" id="img2" onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" src="http://bit.ly/1ug1e6" /> 
<img alt="Image Not Loaded" id="img3" onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" src="http://bit.ly/1yIAYc" /> 
<img alt="Image Not Loaded" id="img4" onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" src="http://bit.ly/2LHyDW" /> 
<img alt="Image Not Loaded" id="img5" onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" src="http://bit.ly/2wyHSR" /> 
<img alt="Image Not Loaded" id="img6" onmouseover="preview.src=img6.src" src="http://bit.ly/yRo1i" /></div>


    <div align="center" class="preview"><img alt="No Image Loaded" id="preview" src="http://bit.ly/2rz3hy" /></div>
    </div>
```

So, I don't know how to call the image so it displays in my thumbnail then displays into the larger gallery image.
I really hope this post makes sense. I have been frustrated forever and am really not a good programmer AT ALL so any help would truly be appreciated. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: are u using asp.net ?

Comment: No, I am just going off of other things that I have seen on the internet / myself